# If program executes in 2seconds with n=10, how much time will it take to execute n=100?

Tags: c, algorithm

If a program executes in 2seconds with n=10, how much time will it take to execute n=100 with complexity n * log(n)? I thought about it and I think it's probably 4seconds, but how can I prove it?

Comment: Do some math? Sounds like homework...

Comment: There is no way to know without studying and/or measuring the individual program. Complexity is about limits as problem size tends to infinity. It could take no time at all or take three hours for n=100 and still be O(n log(n)).

Comment: you can only reason in terms of complexity or number of operations: the executing time highly depends on the running machine (number, complexity and priority of all the other programs running).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the time taken is exactly proportional to n*log(n), and not just an upper bound (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations), you'd have:

```
executionTime = (constant) * n * log(n)
```

Plug in n=10 and solve for the constant.  Now you have an expression for the execution time at every n.

Answer (score 3):

Well, consider the following:

10 operations complete in 2 seconds in the linear case, ie: O(n), so `n` operations, meaning 10 operations:

```
==> 10 * k = 2s
==> k = 0.2 (seconds per operation)
```

With complexity (ie: Big-Oh) of O(n*log(n)), you would have this many operations:

```
==> n * log(n)
==> 100 * log(100)
==> 100 * 2 = 200
```

Now, with 0.2seconds/operation, for 200 operations, with an algorithm of complexity O(n*log(n)), we get:

```
==> T = 0.2s/operation * 200 operations = 40 seconds
```

This is a pretty good result. In the linear case, (ie: O(n)) the savings aren't that much better, ie:

```
==> T = 0.2s/operation * 100 operations = 20 seconds
```

While if this were O(n^2), it would be horrendous:

```
==> T = 0.2s/operation * (100^2) = 0.2*10,000 = 2000 seconds
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Would it make more sense to use base 2 logarithm instead of 10? Then you'd get closer to 133 seconds.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/6701809/10077

Comment: @FredLarson Converting between is two constant bases is just a constant factors, so the base of the logarithm in `O(<whatever> log n)` does not matter. Which is yet another example of why big O is of no use predicting actual run time.

Comment: @delnan: True. Which means Patricia Shanahan's comment is really the correct answer here.

Comment: Attempting to calculate an exact value in the theoretical sense is possible in this case, keeping in mind the logarithmic base was not defined explicitly. In either case (ie: natural base, or 10-base), we get the same relative ratios, and know the relative increase/decrease in performance. If this were an actual real-world case, people would be doing application profiling and statistics, not big-Oh calculations and algebra.

Comment: @FredLarson As log(100)/log(10) = 2 in any base ( as 100 = 10 to the power of 2 - that's what logarithms mean ), and 100/10 = 10, the complexity of something which scales as N ln N will increase 20 times if you increase N from 10 to 100 whatever base log you use.

Answer (score 2):

for n=10, the program at worst case takes 10*log(10) = 10 operations.

then for n=100, it takes 100*log(100) = 200 operations.

```
10 operations  --> 2 seconds
200 operations --> X seconds

X = 40 second.
```

Comment: Would it make more sense to use base 2 logarithm instead of 10? Then you'd get closer to 133 seconds.

Comment: @FredLarson: You get exactly the same answer no matter what log base you use, as long as you use the same log base in both cases.  That's why the log base doesn't need to be specified.  Eg with base 2, you get ~33.22 operations for n = 10 and ~664.4 operations for n = 100 - the ratio is the same.