# Algorithmic complexity: Factors deciding base of lagarithms

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, logarithm

What are the factors which decide the base of the logarithm in case of logarithmic complexities? I have read related questions on the SO (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701809/base-of-logarithms-in-time-complexity-algorithms)). In case of the binary search, binary tree traversals etc. the base of the log is 2, as the data is divided into two each time. But I still can't understand/think of examples of other bases. What are the examples of other bases of logarithmic complexities?

Comment: Multiplying by a constant doesn't change the complexity, but it's all that is needed to change the base, so the base is immaterial.

Comment: @Beta: Base of the log makes difference in case if logarithmic function is in the exponent. Although it will not be often.

Comment: How about a [ternary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search_tree)?

Comment: @close_voter: Care to explain the reason?

Comment: The answer to the question you linked ([base of logarithms in time-complexity algorithms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701809/base-of-logarithms-in-time-complexity-algorithms) ) is correct: the base is meaningless when talking about algorithm complexity. You seem to be thinking too much in terms of (accurate) mathematics. In this field "logarithmic" is only an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

Changing from one base to another involves multiplying by a constant, which doesn't change the complexity, so the choice of base is immaterial. O(log(N)) = O(log(N)).

For example, if some algorithm involves a number of steps that approaches K = 1.23 log<sub>2</sub>(N) in the limit of large N, where N is some parameter of the problem, then the limit can also be written as K = 3.45 log<sub>7</sub>(N).

Having the *complexity* in an *exponent* is something I've never heard of before. I think the only way it makes any sense at all goes something like this: **Z = B<sup>O(log(N))</sup>** means that there exists a constant M such that for all sufficiently large N, Z ≤ B<sup>M ln(N)</sup>.

Comment: Please take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Quasi-polynomial_time

Comment: @0xc0de: Sure enough, a big-O expression in an exponent. And my interpretation was correct; the base doesn't matter.

Comment: Consider `O(N^log_k(N))`. For N=256 and base 2 & 16, `O(N^log_2(N))` ie. O(n^8)  differs from `O(N^log_16(N))` ie O(n^2) as a polynomial of the order of 8 to a quadratic. Its not a change by a multiplicative/additive constant and can't be ignored.

Comment: @0xc0de: O(N^log_2(N)) is not O(N^8), and O(N^log(N)) is not O(log(N)).

Comment: I just simplified the expression with value N=256 and k=2, 16; with which it becomes O(n^2) from O(n^8) on changing the base of the log from 2 to 16. And my question didn't restrict anyone to O(log(N)). Please don't assume it. I definitely know O(N^log(N)) is different.

Answer (score 0):

When you solve a big problem usually you divide it into smaller parts, the so called divide and conquer, for example, in the Quick Sort algorithm, in each phase, the size of the array is halved until the size is small enough and the solution becomes trivial. Here The factor is two because in each phase the size of the problem is divided by 2. Here is another example:

**Convert a decimal number to string**

```
while (n > 0) {
    digits.add(n % 10);
    n /= 10;
}
print digits.reverse();
```

I each iteration *n* is reduced to a tenth. So the complexity of the algorithm is O(log_10 n) . For example, if n = 1,000,000,000 then the algorithm will terminate at most after 9 steps = log_10 (1,000,000,000). If *n* is in base *k* then in the `while` replace 10 by *k* and the complexity becomes O(log_k n).