# find time and space complexity

Tags: c, time-complexity, space-complexity

I need to find the time and space complexity of `f3`.
I think that `g` has space complexity of `log(n)`, so for the time complexity, but I am not really sure how I find the time and space complexity of `f3` because the calling for `g` is inside the `for` commend, does it mean the `g` is being called every time to check if `g(i) < n`?

```c
int g(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) 
        return 1;
    return g(n / 2) + 1;
}

int f3(int n)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; g(i) < n; ++i)
        ++counter;
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: How many times does f3 call g?

Answer (score 0):

As `g(n)` will run in `Theta(log(n))` and each time adds 1 to the final result, the final value of `g(i)` will be `\ceil{log(i)} + 1`. On the other hand, the loop inside `f3` will run while `g(i) < n`. It means the loop will iterate up to `2^n`. Hence, `f3` will run `2^n` times. Hence, the **time complexity of `f3(n) = sum_{i=1}^{2^n} log(i) = log((2^n)!) =  \Theta(n * 2^n)`** (as `log((2^n)!) ~ (2^n) log(2^n)`).

About space complexity, the maximum depth of `g(i)`, will be when `i = 2^n`, which is `n` (`n` recursive calls). Hence, the **space complexity of `f3` will be `\Theta(n)`.**

Answer (score 0):

***In short:***
*Time complexity* of f3(n) = ***O(2^n)***

*Space complexity* of f3(n) = ***O(n)***

Space and Time complexity of g(n) = O(log(n))

Note: (here all log that I refer are log base2 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701809/base-of-logarithms-in-time-complexity-algorithms) and all notations are in Big O notation)

***Details:***

The function "g()" returns floor(log(n))+1. The loop in function "f3()" cotinues until the function 'g()' returns n.  For g(i) to return 'n', i needs to be '2^(n-1)'.

In order to terminate the loop in "f3()", 'i' needs to reach 2^(n-1). So 'g()' is called 2^(n-1) times.

So **Time complexity of "f3()"** = 2^(n-1) x (time complexity of g()) = 2^n x (log n) = **O(2^n)**

Largest memory used will be during the last call of 'g(i)' where i==2^(n-1).

Therefore  **space complexity of "f3()"** = log(2^(n-1)) = **O(n)**

Comment: The inference “So Time complexity of "f3()" = 2^n x (time complexity of g())” is not valid: While f3 may iterate 2^n times, it calls g with a varying argument, so the complexity of f3 is a sum of the complexities of various calls to g, not a product of a single complexity. The Big O complexity may work out the same, but this is not shown in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out "floor(log(n))+1", I missed to consider g(powers of 2) else it satisfies ceil(log(n)).

Comment: Its mentioned in the answer as "Note" that all complexity calculations are for Big O and all logs are of base 2.

Comment: If your second comment, referring to the Note, is a response to my statement that the inference about the time complexity is not valid, then it is irrelevant. This issue is not with Big O notation or the base of the logarithm. The issue is that the complexity of `for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) q(i)` is not, in general, a complexity of N times the complexity of q(i). For example, if q(i) takes exactly 2^i steps, O(q(i)) = 2^i. But the complexity of the loop is not N•q(N-1). The calls to q in the loop will take 1+2+4+8+…2^i = 2^N−1 steps. The complexity of that loop is O(2^N).

Comment: Via "Note" I meant to say that all calculations are valid only in the calculation for Big O. I do accept that the exact time complexity cannot be taken in general for N times. But considering Big O it will just lead to O(2^n).